# Why is string/json sent in post request to .netcore web api resulting in null?

Tags: json, angular, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have an array that I'm converting to JSON using JSON.stringify

```
const arrayOfUpdatesAsJSON = JSON.stringify(this.ArrayOfTextUpdates);
```

This outputs some valid JSON.

```
[{"key":"AgentName","value":"Joe Blogs"},{"key":"AgentEmail","value":"Joe@test.com"}]
```

As I'm going to be sending JSON to the server I set the content type to application/json

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};
```

When a button is pressed I make the request with the url, body and header.

```
try {
  this.httpservice
    .post(
      url,
      arrayOfUpdatesAsJSON,
      httpOptions
    )
    .subscribe(result => {
      console.log("Post success: ", result);
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

This works fine and hits the method I'm expecting inside the api.

```
    [HttpPost("{id:length(24)}", Name = "UpdateLoan")]
    public IActionResult Update(string id, string jsonString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        ... and some other stuff
    }
```

The ID is populated inside the url builder which populates ok. I would then expect the contents of my variable jsonString inside the api to be populated with the json of my request however it is always null. What am I missing?

Comment: You are sending an array, but expect query parameters (since there is no complex model defined on your controller and webapi doesn't expect `multipart/form-data`/`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

Comment: You're sending *JSON* not a string. Even though the JSON is effectively a "string", you cannot bind it directly to a C# string, because it's interpreted as an object. You'd need to send it as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, like `data: { jsonString: JSON.stringify(foo) }`. Or, you can bind it to something like `List<KeyValuePair>`. I'm not 100% sure that will work, but it's the closest construction to the JSON you're sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to mark `jsonString` with `[FromBody]` to tell model binder bind the parameter from posted json. And because you are expecting plain `string` value you need to pass valid json `string` (not `object`) so you need to call additional `JSON.stringify` in javascript

```
const jsonArray = JSON.stringify(this.ArrayOfTextUpdates);
const arrayOfUpdatesAsJSON = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);

this.httpservice
    .post(
      url,
      arrayOfUpdatesAsJSON,
      httpOptions
)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost("{id:length(24)}", Name = "UpdateLoan")]
public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] string jsonString)
```